# How can i customize toolbar button in Extjs using Compass/Saas?

Tags: extjs, sass, compass-sass

I want to customize toolbar button theme in Extjs using Compass/Sass in order to eliminate the gradient effect.

```
@include extjs-button-ui(
        'my_button',

        $background-gradient:null,
        $background-gradient-over:null,
        $background-gradient-focus:null,
        $background-gradient-pressed:null,
        $background-gradient-disabled: null 
);
```

But it returns compass compile error :

```
WARNING: @theme-background-image: Theme image not found: ../images/btn/btn-topbar_button-corners.gif
         on line 18 of /Users/user/Documents/workspace/sihalon/war/extjs/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/mixins/_theme-background-image.scss

WARNING: @theme-background-image: Theme image not found: ../images/btn/btn-topbar_button-sides.gif
         on line 18 of /Users/user/Documents/workspace/sihalon/war/extjs/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/mixins/_theme-background-image.scss

    error my-ext-theme.scss (Line 693 of _button.scss: Invalid null operation: "null plus 4px".)
overwrite ../css/my-ext-theme.css
```

Comment: Looks like part of the scss is trying manipulate the null value and add on pixels, does 0 work in place of null?

Comment: Do you have verified that your used SASS/Compass version is not out of date? Dou you use the latest version of Ext JS 4?

Answer (score 0):

You must put

```
$icon-size:16px,
```

For example:

```
@include extjs-button-ui(
'yellow',
$background-color:yellow,
$icon-size:16px,
$font-size:18px
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shuold use none for no gradient;

For example:

```
@include extjs-button-ui(
        'my_button',

        $background-gradient:none,
        $background-gradient-over:none,
        $background-gradient-focus:none,
        $background-gradient-pressed:none,
        $background-gradient-disabled: none
);
```